# Is broken Sobolev space a Sobolev space?

Tags: functional-analysis, finite-element-method

The definition of a broken Sobolev space is as follows.
Given infinite-dimensional (but mesh-dependent)
spaces on an open bounded domain $\Omega \in R^3$ with Lipschitz boundary. The mesh, denoted by $\Omega_h$, is a disjoint partitioning of $\Omega$ into open elements $K$ such that the union of their closures
is the closure of $\Omega$. The collection of element boundaries $\partial K$ for all $K \in \Omega_h$, is denoted by
$\partial \Omega_h$. We assume that each element boundary $\partial K$ is Lipschitz. The shape of the elements is
otherwise arbitrary for now. The broken Sobolev space is defined as
$$\hat{H}^{1}\left(\Omega_{h}\right)=\left\{u \in L^{2}(\Omega):\left.u\right|_{K} \in H^{1}(K), K \in \Omega_{h}\right\},$$
where $H^1$ is the standard Sobolev space. According to my understanding, if $\Omega_h$ can be partitioned into a **finite** number of subdomains, $K$'s, and because the union of the intersections of $K$'s is a set of measure zero, then $\forall u \in \hat{H}^1, \int_{\Omega_h} \sum_{|\alpha|\leq 1} (D^\alpha u)^2 dx = \sum_{K=1}^n \int_K  \sum_{|\alpha|\leq 1} (D^\alpha u)^2 dx$. This seems mean that $\hat{H}^{1}$ is also a Sobolev space.

If the partion of $\Omega_h$ consists of an **infinite** number of $K$'s, then the equality of the integration above would not hold. In this case, $\hat{H}^{1}$ is not a Sobolev space.

Am I right about the above two statements? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The definition is not clear: is the subdivision of $\Omega_h$ be given before, or is the definition: if $u$ in the broken space then there is a corresponding partition?

Comment: @daw Thank you very much. I made my question clearer now. Please let me know if there are other things confusing.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, $\hat{H}^1$ is not a Sobolev space, since the functions in $\hat{H}^1$ do not have a weak derivative belonging to any Lebesgue space, e.g. $H^1$ is the space of functions in $L^2$ with weak derivatives in $L^2$. A broken Sobolev space simply means that the functions belongs to Sobolev spaces on each individual element.

The second question is very interesting, and the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.07215 considers the notion of limiting broken Sobolev spaces (see the Definition 4.1). Here, the infinite partition $\Omega_\infty$ is obtained by iteratively refining the mesh of the domain, so that one does obtain an infinite collection of elements. The corresponding limit space is not a classical Sobolev space (unless the refinement of the domain eventually refines everywhere), but it does have similar characteristics.